# How I avoid brute force searching in hash search

Tags: java, dynamic, hash, brute-force

I have a program in java which takes an input string and generate a hash value using MD5 algorithm. The program searches a particular pattern (e.g 118855) in the generated hash string in each iteration by varying the last part of the input string by appending it with an integer which is incremented by one in each pass.

For example, if the input string is xyz then I will first find the hash for xyz0 and then for xyz1 and then for xyz2 and so no using MD5. In each pass it will search for a pattern eg 12345 in each hash value. Until this pattern is found the program will not stop.

Now my question is that how to avoid the brute force approach in searching this pattern in these generated hash strings. In other words, how can I jump the integer by a dynamic value instead of one each time?

**Note: All the above hashes are generated using MD5. I am not requesting for replacement for MD5. Also, I not finding a collision in two hash value. My concern is to find a given substring pattern in these generated hash value.**

Comment: There are bunch of cryptographically strong and proven algorithms exist. Sure you want to roll your own?

Comment: @IstvánRábel don't want my own algo for MD5 replacement. I just updated my question to make it clear.

Comment: Ah, my bad. Misunderstood your problem. More clear now :) In that case, you may stick with brute force, as the point of hashing is that you can't really figure out the opposite direction.

Comment: More information is needed, see my coment to the answer provided by @Ralf Kleberhoff.

Answer (score 3):

If it were possible to tell in advance what to append to your "xyz" string (instead of brute-force search) so the MD5 hash contains a given pattern, then the algorithm were useless.

Message digest algorithms are meant to make cheating near-impossible, so constructing a manipulated document that still gives the same hash value as the original one, should be computationally very hard.

MD5 isn't the cryptographically strongest available hashing algorithm, but surely you can't just somehow "construct" a plain text to give some specified MD5 hash (or hash pattern). If that were possible, people had thrown away MD5 long ago.

Unless you are a cryptography guru, I'd recommend to stay with the brute-force approach.

[EDIT]

The number of tries to find a N-digit pattern should roughly be `16^N / (33-N)` (not corrected for double matches), e.g. 2500 tries for a 4-digit pattern or 40000 tries for a 5-digit pattern. So, depending on the pattern length, that looks doable to me.

[EDIT]

To explain the "calculation":

MD5 is written as 32 hex digits.

So if you want to find a specific 5-digit pattern in front of the hash, there are 16^5 different possibilities, so the probability to get the correct one with a single attempt is 1/16^5, thus needing roughly 16^5 attempts until you succeed.

But we don't care about the position where in the hash we find our pattern, so now there are 28 positions where we have a chance to find our pattern. This roughly multiplies the match probability by 28 (this isn't exact, as this calculation counts a double match twice where the pattern is contained at two different positions). So that factor divides the expected number of attempts.

Comment: This. Basically the question boils down to "is there a collision generator for the cryptographic hash function that I'm using?". If it's a cryptographically sound hash function, the answer should always be "no".

Comment: I am not developing an algorithm in replacement of MD5 instead my task is to develop a program to find a specific pattern in the generated hash. I will just update the question with example.

Comment: @PiotrWilkin I am not finding a collision generator. I have just find a substring within hash value.

Comment: How do you get 16^N / (33-N)?

Comment: md5 **is** is broken. Since 2010 at the latest, it should no longer be used. But even before that it was not advisable to use it.

Comment: That "MD5 is written as 32 hex digits" is not in the question. MD5 generates a 128-bit hash value. How it is represented is a separate issue and unfortunately specified by the OP. It is also not clear it is a 5 character match that is wanted, the question provides two examples: `118855` and `12345`. Note that both examples are decimal digits, no hexadecimal [a-f] digits. It is also possible that the MD5 hash is expected to be rendered as a 128-bit integer which more closely matches the examples to be matched. There is simply not enough information in the question to support the answer.

Comment: @zaph Could you point me to a place where MD5 isn't written as 32 hex digits? Of course, 128 bits can be written in many different ways, but with MD5, so far I've only seen 32 hex digits.

Comment: 1. Base64. 2. Where in the question do you see a hex character a-f? 3. Even it one assumes hex MD5 output the question still seems to be looking for a decimal string of characters. 4. How many digits are wanted: 5 or 6? 5. In my usages of cryptographic hashes I generally do not use a display representation, just the binary output. 5. My main point is that that question is ambiguous, see my comment to the question. Providing a concrete answer to such an ambiguous question is not really possible